# Python: modularizing large file

Tags: python

I have a python source file with a few classes in it. These classes require roughly the same imports, and rely on each other: each references some of the others in its methods.

Semantically speaking, these classes form a single module. They belong in the same file.

The problem is that they have grown. Each class now spans well over a hundred lines, and that's after refactoring to keep their methods simple. The file is slow to navigate, often modified at different points, and hard to keep track of mentally.

If I break all this into smaller files, I'll find that each file has the same imports, and that they must import each other circularly.

**How can I modularize this code?**

*Note: the fact that these classes are large is not outright bad design. They are message dispatchers that have one method for each kind of message they can handle. There is a hierarchy in place that allows for code reuse via inheritance wherever possible.*